# Closing Created jQuery Elements

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i have this problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                 
    $('#buttonTest').click(function() {                        
        $.get('/WebTestProject/ServletEsempio', function(responseJson) {         
            var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#result')); 
            $.each(responseJson, function(index, product) {    
                $('<tr>').appendTo($table)                     
                    .append($('<td>').text(index))       
                    .append($('<td>').text(product))    
            });
        });
    });
});
```

this code is OK for calling my servlet, but i dont find how to close the TAG ,  and .
is it possible?

many thanks to all.

Comment: For most browsers, if you observe the DOM after this runs, it automatically closes the tag.

Comment: How to close what tag. DOM Nodes can't exist without both a closing and opening tag or self closing, the browser will create the closing tag if it is missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create elements using jQuery in this fashion, they are created *automatically closed*. However, even the jQuery documentation recommends that you close it explicitly:

> To ensure cross-platform compatibility, the snippet must be well-formed. Tags that *can* contain other elements should be paired with a closing tag:
>
> ie: `$('<table />');` or `$('<table></table>');`
>
> Tags that **cannot** contain elements may be quick-closed or not:
>
> ie: `$('<img />');` or `$('<input>');`

*Source*: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to the `table` element you are creating, it will be closed for you automatically as jQuery relies on javascripts' `createElement()` function to create elements.

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> When the parameter has a single tag (with optional closing tag or quick-closing) — `$('<img />')` or `$('<img>')`, `$('<a></a>')` or `$('<a>')` — jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript `createElement()` function.

Answer (score 1):

From the jQUery doku (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ ):

> Creating New Elements
>
> If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the
>   string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it has  somewhere
>   within the string). If not, the string is interpreted as a selector
>   expression, as explained above. But if the string appears to be an
>   HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described
>   by the HTML. Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers
>   to these elements. You can perform any of the usual jQuery methods on
>   this object: $('My *new*
>   text
>
> ').appendTo('body');
>
> If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as
>   it is in the above example, the actual creation of the elements is
>   handled by the browser's innerHTML mechanism. In most cases, jQuery
>   creates a new  element and sets the innerHTML property of the
>   element to the HTML snippet that was passed in. When the parameter has
>   a single tag (with optional closing tag or quick-closing) — $('') or $(''), $('') or $('') — jQuery creates the
>   element using the native JavaScript createElement() function.