# Json array inside array, to make them as title with childrens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

For my case, I have a json file stored much of cates. Then, each cate has different amount of subject inside.

[I made a simulate on codepen, the code and json also stored there](https://codepen.io/sctw/pen/QqXyEV)

I used `$.each` to get all the data result. But I don't know how to make them like Title->Subject(s) list, Title->Subject(s) list, Title->Subject(s) list...
My json structure is:

```
{
    "cate": [
        {
            "cateName": "Cate 1",
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "subjectName": "Subject 1"
                },
                {
                    "subjectName": "Subject 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "cateName": "Cate 2",
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "subjectName": "Subject 1"
                },
                {
                    "subjectName": "Subject 2"
                },
                {
                    "subjectName": "Subject 3"
                },
                {
                    "subjectName": "Subject 4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "cateName": "Cate 3",
            "subjects": [
                {
                    "subjectName": "Subject 1"
                },
                {
                    "subjectName": "Subject 2"
                },
                {
                    "subjectName": "Subject 3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The html structure must output like that:

```
<div id="mobileCateContainer">
  <div class="cate">
    <span class="cateHead">Cate 1</span>
    <div class="cateBody">
      <ul>
        <li>Subject 1</li>
        <li>Subject 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cate">
    <span class="cateHead">Cate 2</span>
    <div class="cateBody">
      <ul>
        <li>Subject 1</li>
        <li>Subject 2</li>
        <li>Subject 3</li>
        <li>Subject 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cate">
    <span class="cateHead">Cate 3</span>
    <div class="cateBody">
      <ul>
        <li>Subject 1</li>
        <li>Subject 2</li>
        <li>Subject 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Very thanks for answer my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forEach()` and `map()` to loop and build data and then `appendTo` to append to elements.

```js
var data = {"cate":[{"cateName":"Cate 1","subjects":[{"subjectName":"Subject 1"},{"subjectName":"Subject 2"}]},{"cateName":"Cate 2","subjects":[{"subjectName":"Subject 1"},{"subjectName":"Subject 2"},{"subjectName":"Subject 3"},{"subjectName":"Subject 4"}]},{"cateName":"Cate 3","subjects":[{"subjectName":"Subject 1"},{"subjectName":"Subject 2"},{"subjectName":"Subject 3"}]}]}

var p = $('#mobileCateContainer');

var html = data.cate.forEach(function(e) {
  var cate = $('<div class="cate" />')
  
  $('<div class="cateHead" />')
    .text(e.cateName)
    .appendTo(cate)
  
  $('<div class="cateBody" />')
    .append($('<ul />').html(e.subjects.map(s => '<li>' + s.subjectName + '</li>' )))
    .appendTo(cate)
  
  p.append(cate)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mobileCateContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Another question is about your code, this is first time I see "$('<div class="cate">')". Is this style of coding will automatically close the element tag?

Comment: Its better to close it but i guess you don't have to, you can read few questions about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757482/creating-an-empty-element-with-start-tag-vs-self-closing-tag, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917043/closing-created-jquery-elements, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555898/jquery-when-creating-a-new-element-do-i-need-the-ending-taghttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555898/jquery-when-creating-a-new-element-do-i-need-the-ending-tag

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what is this mean "(e.subjects.map(s => '<li>' + s.subjectName + '</li>' ))". Can you explain it? s=> is for what?

Comment: `s` is current element in map method loop, so for each element you take subject name and wrap it in `li`

Comment: `=>` is what meaning?

Comment: That is just arrow function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Oh, this is a short form, how about don't use arrow function, how its look like? Because I still not too understand about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the depth of the JSON you can simply map the json object to html, the code below is not requiring jquery and is triggering browser to reflow only once.

```
document.getElementById("mobileCateContainer").innerHTML = data.cate.map(mapCates).join('');

function mapCates(obj){
     var catestart = '<div class="cate">'+
    '<span class="cateHead">'+obj.cateName+'</span>'+
    '<div class="cateBody"><ul>';
    var cateSubjects = obj.subjects.map(mapSubjects).join('');
    var cateend =  '</ul></div></div>';
  return catestart + cateSubjects + cateend;
}

function mapSubjects(obj){
        return '<li>'+ obj.subjectName + '</li>';
}
```